# Is there a way to generate a matrix-free decomposition for a matrix-free operator?

Tags: numerics, iterative-method, matrix-factorization, matrix-free

Hypothetical question for some code that I'm writing. Suppose I have an matrix-free linear operator $A$, i.e. the only thing I know about it is the forward action $v \mapsto Av$. For simplicity, let's further assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Are there any methods that would allow me to generate a 'decomposition' of this operator without needing to build it explicitly? Considering, say, a Cholesky decomposition: Is there a way to obtain an operator $L$ such that $L L^T v = Av$? Whether $L$ itself is a fully constructed matrix or not.

I suppose you could just use a regular Cholesky algorithm, and everytime you want to access element $A_{ij}$ you compute $e_i A e_j$, but perhaps there's a more performant or iterative way?

Stepping away from Cholesky, is there any 'factorization' I can realistically (meaning with just matrix-applies) perform on a matrix-free operator?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I can't comment specifically on computing a matrix-free computation of a Cholesky factor, but one can compute many matrix functions $f(A)$ using Krylov methods. $f(z) = z^{1/2}$ provides one such decomposition. Some resources can be found here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11369/applying-matrix-square-root-inverse-in-matrix-free-regime

Comment: @whpowell96 True, but it all boils down to what OP needs the Cholesky factor for. If it's to solve linear systems, then having $A^{1/2}$ instead of the Cholesky factor does not work; if it is for normalization purposes then the two might be equivalent. OP, if you could tell us more it would be helfpul; this might be an XY problem.

Comment: I think OP is missing the point of the matrix-free approach to begin with: rather than computing a Cholesky factor (or whatever else) and storing it in memory, we should ask ourselves what we would *do* with the Cholesky factor, and try to get at that directly using just matrix-vector products. Maybe I want a Cholesky factor because I want to solve a linear system as well as compute a determinant: then do those things directly using, say Lanczos.

Answer (score 6):

This is not efficient, primarily because (i) the factors of sparse matrices are, in general, not sparse themselves, and (ii) when computing matrix factorizations, you don't just need $A_{ij}$ but you start with them and then you *update* them -- i.e., you have to allocate storage for them anyway, and so it isn't useful to try and start with a matrix-free representation: You need a matrix representation anyway.